# How to setup a local server which can accept oAuth callbacks?

Tags: php, apache, localhost

I am not sure if this question has a place over here but I am having a lot of trouble setting up a local development server from where I can work on Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and other applications.

As of now I have an Apache environment and I am working on a PHP based platform. The database server is a standard MySQL server. Also, I am working behind a authentication based proxy.

The primary issue that I encounter is, when I made an application on Twitter and entered the relevant details like - `website`, `callbackurl` as `127.0.0.1`. My application when tried to retrieve the oAuth key, it wasn't able to. I even tried out changing my listening post to something other than `80`, but it didn't work either.

I understand that any application of this sort will encounter this problem because `127.0.0.1` is not an address that points to my computer precisely. And I am not aware of any other method other than this. Am I doing something wrong somewhere or is it impossible to develop/test applications which require oAuth via a locally deployed server.

### Update

Port forwarding is not a solution because I am behind a firewall and I am part of a private network. Hence, my questions are-

Is this kind of development impossible in such a setup? If yes, then what can I do to? If I work using a dongle, will it possible? Or do I need to procure a static IP?

Comment: Read some documentation to learn how netowrk communication works first (addresses, routing). You will not succeed if you do not understand the basics, sorry.

Comment: @arkascha I have read a lot on addresses and routing. But, I have never come across any questions regarding this before.